# Lilypond transposing for a B-flat clarinet

Tags: lilypond

I've written a score for a short piece for violin and cello in Lilypond.

```
\version "2.20"

\header {
  title =   "Transpose Example"
}

main =  {
  \key g \major
  \numericTimeSignature \time 3/4
  \clef "treble"
  \tempo 4 = 84
  \relative g' {
  % motif primary sequence
  g8\mf d'8 b8 d4 b8 | d8~ d16 b16 g16 r16 g16 a16~ a4 | 
  g8 d'8 b8 d4 b8 | d16 c16 b16 r16 g8 b4~ b8 |
    \bar "||"
  }
}

cello = {
  \key g \major
  \clef "bass"
  \relative g' {
  R2.*4
  }
}

\score {
  \new StaffGroup = "StaffGroup" <<
    \context Staff = "clarinet" \with { instrumentName = "Violin" }<<
      \main
      \set Staff.midiInstrument = "violin"
    >>
    \context Staff = "cello" \with { instrumentName = "Cello" } <<
      \cello
      \set Staff.midiInstrument = "cello"
    >>
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

[image]

But I now want to set the Violin staff for a B-flat clarinet (which is a transposing instrument). Is there any easy way to have Lilypond produce the B-flat Clarinet staff when the notes are written in the target sound (concert pitch)?

The `\transposition pitch` command seems to be for when you have written for the instrument and you want the midi output to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\transpose c d { ... }`. Make sure you are including all parts that need to be transposed within that `\transpose` block. The `c` and the `d` are just telling you how far to transpose — in this case, up two semitones (down two semitones would be `c bes,`).

```
global = {
 \key g \major
 \time 3/4
}
main = \relative c' {
 c4 d e
}
cello = \relative c {
 \clef bass
 c4 d e
}
\score {
 <<
  \new StaffGroup <<
   \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Violin"
   } {
    \global
    \main
   }
   \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Cello"
   } {
    \global
    \cello
   }
  >>
 >>
 \layout {}
}
\score {
 <<
  \new StaffGroup <<
   \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Clarinet"
   } \transpose c d {
    \global
    \main
   }
   \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Cello"
   } {
    \global
    \cello
   }
  >>
 >>
 \layout {}
}
```

[image: Showing LilyPond transposition is easy]

Comment: Thankyou! I also added \transposition bes so that the midi file sounds the clarinet correctly

Comment: Perhaps `\transpose bes, c {...}` makes more sense than `\transpose c d {...}` for a B-flat instrument.

Comment: Just depends on how you look at it. Whatever helps.